# How could I get the process runtime when the process terminated

Tags: c#, winforms

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Process.Start("notepad");
            for(; ; )
            {
                var pname = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");
                foreach (var proc in pname)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (pname.Length == 0) // when the process("notepad") is terminated
                        {
                            textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now - proc.StartTime);//textbox1.text = process(notepad)run time
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("trouble");
                        
                    }
                    
                }
                
            }
            
        }
```

Um... my goal is when the notepad has terminated the runtime showed in textbox1.text;
I think maybe the problem is "for and break"

Comment: [`Process.Start` returns a `Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?view=net-5.0#System_Diagnostics_Process_Start_System_String_), and `Process` has a [`WaitForExit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.waitforexit?view=net-5.0) method. I'm sure you could do something there to time how long the process is running for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of blocking your UI with `WaitForExit()`, capture the returned `Process`, turn on [EnableRaisingEvents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.enableraisingevents?view=netframework-4.5.2), then wire up the [Exited](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.exited?view=netframework-4.5.2) event.  You'll need to marshal back to the UI thread for your update though (many different ways to do that):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Process P = Process.Start("notepad");
    P.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    P.Exited += P_Exited;
}

private void P_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Process P = (Process)sender;
    textBox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
    {
        textBox1.Text = (DateTime.Now - P.StartTime).ToString();
    });            
}
```

If you'd rather have it all within the button click handler:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.Enabled = false;
    Process P = Process.Start("notepad");
    await Task.Run(() => {
        P.WaitForExit();
    });
    textBox1.Text = (DateTime.Now - P.StartTime).ToString();
    button1.Enabled = true;
}
```

Another variation using a loop and [HasExited](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.hasexited?view=netframework-4.5.2):

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.Enabled = false;
    Process P = Process.Start("notepad");
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        while (!P.HasExited)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            textBox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {
                textBox1.Text = (DateTime.Now - P.StartTime).ToString();
            });
        }               
    });
    textBox1.Text = (DateTime.Now - P.StartTime).ToString();
    button1.Enabled = true;
}
```